# Translating XLIFF files using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, translation, xliff

I am translating Xliff file using BeautifulSoup and googletrans packages. I managed to extract all  strings and translate them and managed to replace  strings by creating new tag with a translations, e.g.

```xml
<trans-unit id="100890::53706_004">
<source>Continue in store</source>
<target>Kontynuuj w sklepie</target>
</trans-unit>
```

The problem appears when the source tag has other  tags inside.

e.g.

```xml
<source><x ctype="x-htmltag" equiv-text="&lt;b&gt;" id="html_tag_191"/>Choose your product\
<x ctype="x-htmltag" equiv-text="&lt;/b&gt;" id="html_tag_192"/>From a list: </source>
```

There are different numbers of these  tags and different order of where string appears. E.g. `<source> text1 <x /> <x/> text2 <x/> text3 </source>`. Each x tag is unique with different id and attributes.

Is there a way to modify the text inside the tag without having to create a new tag?
I was thinking I could extract x tags and its attributes but the order or string and x tag in different code lines differs a lot I'm not sure how to do that.
Maybe there is other package better suited for translating xliff files?

Comment: in question add expected result for this `<source>`. With BeautifulSoup probably you would have to use `for`-loop or `list()` to get all children inside `<source>` and work with them.

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to show what output you want for a given source

Comment: There are numerous tools (mostly commercial, some free) that make XLIFF translation a breeze. Try a search for "CAT tools".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `for`-loop to work with all children in `source`.
And you can duplicate them with `copy.copy(child)` and `append` to `target`.
At the same time you can check if `child` is `NavigableString` and convert it.

---

```
text = '''<source><x ctype="x-htmltag" equiv-text="&lt;b&gt;" id="html_tag_191"/>Choose your product\
<x ctype="x-htmltag" equiv-text="&lt;/b&gt;" id="html_tag_192"/>From a list: </source>'''

conversions = {
    'Choose your product': 'Wybierz swój produkt',
    'From a list: ': 'Z listy: ',
}

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from bs4.element import NavigableString
import copy

#soup = BS(text, 'html.parser')  # it has problem to parse it
#soup = BS(text, 'html5lib')     # it has problem to parse it
soup = BS(text, 'lxml')

# create `<target>`
target = soup.new_tag('target')

# add `<target>` after `<source>
source = soup.find('source')
source.insert_after('', target)

# work with children in `<source>`
for child in source:
    print('type:', type(child))

    # duplicate child and add to `<target>`
    child = copy.copy(child)
    target.append(child)

    # convert text and replace in child in `<target>`        
    if isinstance(child, NavigableString):
        new_text = conversions[child.string]
        child.string.replace_with(new_text)

print('--- target ---')
print(target)
print('--- source ---')
print(source)
print('--- soup ---')
print(soup)
```

Result (little reformated to make it more readable):

```
type: <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
type: <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
type: <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
type: <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>

--- target ---

<target>
  <x ctype="x-htmltag" equiv-text="&lt;b&gt;" id="html_tag_191"></x>
  Wybierz swój produkt
  <x ctype="x-htmltag" equiv-text="&lt;/b&gt;" id="html_tag_192"></x>
  Z listy: 
</target>

--- source ---

<source>
  <x ctype="x-htmltag" equiv-text="&lt;b&gt;" id="html_tag_191"></x>
  Choose your product
  <x ctype="x-htmltag" equiv-text="&lt;/b&gt;" id="html_tag_192"></x>
  From a list: 
</source>

--- soup ---

<html><body>
<source>
  <x ctype="x-htmltag" equiv-text="&lt;b&gt;" id="html_tag_191"></x>
  Choose your product
  <x ctype="x-htmltag" equiv-text="&lt;/b&gt;" id="html_tag_192"></x>
  From a list: 
</source>
<target>
  <x ctype="x-htmltag" equiv-text="&lt;b&gt;" id="html_tag_191"></x>
  Wybierz swój produkt
  <x ctype="x-htmltag" equiv-text="&lt;/b&gt;" id="html_tag_192"></x>
  Z listy: 
</target>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract the two text entries from within `<source>`, you could use the following approach:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = """<source><x ctype="x-htmltag" equiv-text="&lt;b&gt;" id="html_tag_191"/>Choose your product\
<x ctype="x-htmltag" equiv-text="&lt;/b&gt;" id="html_tag_192"/>From a list: </source>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
print(list(soup.source.stripped_strings))
```

Giving you:

```
['Choose your product', 'From a list:']
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not to parse XLIFF files with a generic XML parser. Instead, try to find a specialized XLIFF toolkit. There are a few python projects around, but I don't have experience with them (me: Java guy mostly).

Comment: Not sure if you're running on MacOS but I built a free to try XLIFF Tool that automatically translates XLIFF using Google Translation API. And it might be a great no-code solution. As a developer I get the instinct to write everything myself but sometimes it's best to run with something that's specially designed for the job :)

It's free to try and you can download it [here](https://www.xlifflocalizer.com)! 